# JPanel auto resize

Tags: java, jframe, resize, jpanel

*Reading through SO questions. Sadly no solution worked for me.*

My problem is, I have a JPanel:

[image]

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setName("contentPane");
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100,305, 403);
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);
```

This one has fixed elements. When I enter another project from the "projekt" combobox I might have the chance (dependent on the project) that I get added elements. Input fields or comboboxes. These elements are in a different JPanel which lies ontop of the other JPanel.

```
this.zusatzPanel = new JPanel();
zusatzPanel.setName("zusatzPanel");
this.zusatzPanel.setLayout(null);
this.zusatzPanel.setBounds(11, 301, 270, 713);
```

[image]

When this is the case I need more space (in this case I have enough space but there could be more elements added), but I found no clue how to make the JPanel resize. I believe that I need to make both resizeable.

**with too many added elements:**

[image: with too many added elements]

I also tried with `contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` but that did not do anything.

***EDIT:*** tried `jframe.pack();` changed the Jpanel to make is smaller to test it out. But did not work. Or did i do something wrong?

[image]

```
this.pack();
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setName("contentPane");
contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100,305, 203);
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);
```

Comment: I think you can use a `CardLayout` for this problem. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) anyways.

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly Sadly did not work

Comment: Damn. Although I've never used a CardLayout personally, the documentation would suggest that is the perfect solution for this type of problem. On another note; have you tried using a JScrollPane? It may work.

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly When i apply it to the big JPanel it does nothing, and when i apply it to the small one, the elements in it are no longer shown. I will try the scrollpane. But it would be better that it scales :/

Comment: So you want the JFrame to resize when the JPanel you add grows in size? I haven't tried this before but `pack()` might work (called on JFrame).

Comment: Try calling pack after you create the new JPanel. Also, I don't think you're using the CardLayout correctly. See [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CardLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/CardLayoutDemo.java) to get a better understanding.

Comment: I'd consider adding the "dynamic" elements onto a separate `JPanel` and wrapping that into a `JScrollPane`

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly when i call pack() after creating the new JPanel, the frame shrinks to a tiny point. Maybe i will have to delete the content panes fixed boundries. I will try this and look into the card layout again

Comment: `this.zusatzPanel.setLayout(null);` is a bad idea, it will adversely affect everything you do

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hello again :) The dynamic elements ARE in a different JPanel.

Comment: @CoffeineConverter The drop the `null` layout, use a proper layout manager and wrap it into a `JScrollPane`, the layout manager(s) will allow the `JScrollPane` to do it's work

Comment: @MadProgrammer For example setting the layout of zusatzpanel to borderLayout, gives me strange behavior. Having it null, works currently. If i find something that works better i will change it ofc.

Comment: @CoffeineConverter `GridBagLayout` would be first consideration, but you could use a mixture of layouts, so a `BorderLayout` for the outer container, holding the non-dynamic fields and the `JScrollPane` and possibly a `GridBagLayout` of the dynamic pane. The "static" components would probably sit within the their own `JPanel` and probaly use a `GridBagLayout` as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will try this out. But a question. Because the elements will be added on combobox change event way after the JPanel is created, will it resize automatically or would i need to manage this on combobox change as well?

Comment: You can trigger a layout pass by calling revalidate on the container you've changed, usually you'd call repaint as well